# How to make sense of a summation containing kronecker delta?

Tags: kronecker-delta, kronecker-symbol

first question here so I hope it's appropriate.
I'm looking at the following equation:
[image: equation containing kronecker delta]

And I'm struggling to figure it out. In the sum, there's a symbol that looks like a Kronecker delta (but that the text calls 'the kronecker symbol', which I know is different).
If this is the Kronecker delta as the symbol suggests, doesn't this sum only contain one term (m=0)? As for m=1 and m=2 the delta will be zero, won't it?
If the text is correct in saying it's a Kronecker symbol, how do I calculate that? Have checked a few online sources but they're not clear to me (it's been a long time since high school math).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Whatever your text calls it, it's the Kronecker delta (the Kronecker _symbol_ [looks like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol)). Hint:$$\color{red}{\sum_m(2-\delta_{0,\,m})f_m}=\color{blue}{2\sum_mf_m}-\color{limegreen}{\sum_m\delta_{0,\,m}f_m}=2\sum_mf_m-f_0,$$which for $\sum_m=\sum_{m=0}^2$ simplifies to $f_0+2f_1+2f_2$. Note it's the green term, not the red expression, that only has an $m=0$ contribution.

Answer (score 0):

The notation means $\delta_{.,.}=1$ if the two indices are the same, $\delta_{.,.}=0$ if they differ.
$$
\sum_{m=0}^2 (2-\delta_{0,m})\rho_x^m(\mu_s,\mu_\nu,\varphi-\varphi_0)
\cos[m(\varphi-\varphi_0)] 
= 
[\sum_{m=0}^0+\sum_{m=1}^2] (2-\delta_{0,m})\rho_x^m(\mu_s,\mu_\nu,\varphi-\varphi_0)
\cos[m(\varphi-\varphi_0)]
$$
$$
= 
(2-1)\rho_x^0(\mu_s,\mu_\nu,\varphi-\varphi_0)
\cos[0(\varphi-\varphi_0)]
+ 
\sum_{m=1}^2 (2-0)\rho_x^m(\mu_s,\mu_\nu,\varphi-\varphi_0)
\cos[m(\varphi-\varphi_0)]
$$
$$
= 
\rho_x^0(\mu_s,\mu_\nu,\varphi-\varphi_0)
+ 
2\sum_{m=1}^2 \rho_x^m(\mu_s,\mu_\nu,\varphi-\varphi_0)
\cos[m(\varphi-\varphi_0)]
$$